# Reply to Incoming Media Messages | Twilio Whatsapp API | Internal Server Error

Tags: python, flask, twilio, whatsapp, internal-server-error

I am using Twilio whatsapp API to reply to media messages. Whenever somebody will message me on whatapp with a picture, Twilio will respond with message "Thanks for the image" with a dog picture and if somebody texts the twilio number, then it responds "Send us an image!", again with a dog picture.

When I sent a text message, I am getting a dog picture with text "Send us an image", but the other function is not working. 
[image]

The error I think is in the server I am writing. Because it keeps generating error, even though I am following their [official documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-whatsapp-python), but keeps getting error.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse


app = Flask(__name__)


GOOD_BOY_URL = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518717758536-85ae29035b6d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"


@app.route("/whatsapp", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reply_whatsapp():

    num_media = int(request.values.get("NumMedia"))
    response = MessagingResponse()
    if not num_media:
        msg = response.message("Send us an image!")
    else:
        msg = response.message("Thanks for the image(s).")
    msg.media(GOOD_BOY_URL)
    return str(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\mnauf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:/Users/mnauf/Desktop/IOT/twilio/whatsapp/replyWithMediaToIncomingMsg.py", line 19, in reply_whatsapp
    num_media = int(request.values.get("NumMedia"))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
127.0.0.1 - - [11/May/2019 10:05:02] "GET /whatsapp HTTP/1.1" 500 -
[2019-05-11 10:06:07,095] ERROR in app: Exception on /whatsapp [GET]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it works when you send just a text message, but when you send a message with an image attached, it does not work.

Twilio's tutorial is masking (blurring out) some code to emphasize the changes between steps, and to me it appears that this feature is not working properly, so you're missing some code (the part to handle incoming media attachments).

The complete code is below, and also, **you need to create an `app_data` folder** to store incoming media files.

---

```py
import mimetypes
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from flask import Flask, request
import requests
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse


app = Flask(__name__)


GOOD_BOY_URL = "https://images.unsplash.com/" \
    "photo-1518717758536-85ae29035b6d?" \
    "ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"


@app.route("/whatsapp", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reply_whatsapp():

    num_media = int(request.values.get("NumMedia"))
    media_files = []
    for idx in range(num_media):
        media_url = request.values.get(f'MediaUrl{idx}')
        mime_type = request.values.get(f'MediaContentType{idx}')
        media_files.append((media_url, mime_type))

        req = requests.get(media_url)
        file_extension = mimetypes.guess_extension(mime_type)
        media_sid = os.path.basename(urlparse(media_url).path)

        with open(f"app_data/{media_sid}{file_extension}", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(req.content)

    response = MessagingResponse()
    if not num_media:
        msg = response.message("Send us an image!")
    else:
        msg = response.message("Thanks for the image(s).")
    msg.media(GOOD_BOY_URL)
    return str(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```